# Outlook, change text size in group calender

Tags: calendar, outlook-2007

I need to change the text size in my group calendar. (The calendar that shows an overview of the content of my colleagues calendars)

Can anyone tell me where to do this? - Can't find anything about it using google.

Thx

(Can't post picture of the icon opening the calendar, as I'm new at this site.)

Answer (score 0):

To change the font type that is used in your Calendar, right click an empty space in your Calendar and from the context menu choose: Other Settings

[image]

Here you can set different fonts for the Time, general text and your Monthly calendar. Additionally you can set if certain items should show in bold or not.

Comment: Doing this only changes the font type in my own calendar. It do not change the font in the group calendar. (It's called "gruppetidsplaner" in danish. This is directly translated to "group timetables" in english)